# How long do I need to stay out of South Africa after a 90 day stay, before returning?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, south-africa, visa-free-entry, visa-runs

I stayed in SA from Oct 4th to December 12th.

What date can I return?

Answer (score 2):

There is no rule regarding this, however to avoid being suspected of trying to live in South Africa, you should wait at least as long as you spent in South Africa, and bring as much documentation proving your ties to your home country, in case asked to present it at immigration.

It is also possible you will be let in, but given a shorter period of stay.